# Converting EC private key from string to ECPrivateKey

Tags: java, android, security, jwt, signature

I have EC private key
===BEGIN EC Private Key===
xxxxxxxxx
===END EC Private Key===

How to convert the private key to a proper ECPrivateKeyParameterSpec and generate the private key?

Below code seems to be working but not sure on a way to verify whether  the required private is translated to privaqte key object correctly.

```
        AlgorithmParameters parameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC");
        parameters.init(new ECGenParameterSpec("prime256v1"));
        ECParameterSpec params = parameters.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec.class);
        
        ECPrivateKeySpec ecPrivateKeySpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(<key in utf-8 bytes>), params);
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
        factory.generatePrivate(ecPrivateKeySpec)
```

tried to sign with this private key and verify with the public key but no luck coudnt verify the signature.

Comment: *tried to sign and verify with this private key* - you can't sign and verify with the private key. You sign with the private key and verify with the matching public key.

Comment: i tried to sign with private key and verified with public key no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved it using the PEMParser from the spongy castle and converted it to spongy castle private key, then generated the signature.

Comment: Hi, could you post your solution please?